# Mozilla NSS certutil binary

Tags: firefox, ssl

I have a problem with Firefox 32 and installed SSL certificates in cert8.db and I want to investigate it. I have found out that there is a tool called "certutil" from Mozilla that can work with this file. Microsoft's certutil doesn't work, it has entirely different options.

Unfortunately Mozilla doesn't publish a usable binary of this tool but only provides lengthy documentation about the NSS project itself. Actually I want to investigate the problem with this file and not start into developing some Mozilla software. So setting up a Mozilla build environment is definitely not an option.

If there's some Windows-based Mozilla developers around, could you please provide me a binary of your certutil program? Somebody must have that laying around already so it shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: See here: [Where can I download certutil.exe and the NSS Utils for Windows](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952035#answer-413118), [Mozilla NSS Utils with NSPR (Compiled for download)](https://www.felixrr.pro/archives/165/mozilla-nss-utils-with-nspr-compiled-for-download)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Windows binaries

A few old versions can be found in the [official repository](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/security/nss/releases/). Here are some of the newest binaries compatible with Windows XP and later, both official and unofficial:

- **Version 3.14.2**<sup>2</sup>
  <sub>Built from source code released on February 1, 2013.<sup>3</sup></sub>

  https://onedrive.live.com/?id=8AC323922EA1F60C!1312&cid=8ac323922ea1f60c&authkey=!As8HyT0S8x4uVdc

  The link was originally provided by PRF2 on the Mozilla support forum:

  > [...] I was just posting a link to the updated version of the NSS / NSPR utils as they aren't available to download from the Mozilla website pre-compiled for windows.
  >
  > <sub>Source: [Where can I download certutil.exe and the NSS Utils for Windows](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952035#answer-413118)</sub>
- **Version 3.13.5**<sup>2</sup>
  <sub>Built from source code released on June 1, 2012.<sup>3</sup></sub>

  https://www.felixrr.pro/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/nss-3.13.5-nspr-4.9.1-compiled-x86.zip

  Link found on FelixRR's blog:

  > Anyway the point is to get the tools to do this on Mozilla Firefox you have to compile them.  Someone did put a compiled copy on megaupload.com but since thats been closed down it's no longer available.  I have compiled NSS 3.13.5 with NSPR 4.9.1 for x86 [...]
  >
  > <sub>Source: [Mozilla NSS Utils with NSPR (Compiled for download)](https://www.felixrr.pro/archives/165/mozilla-nss-utils-with-nspr-compiled-for-download)</sub>
- **Version 3.12.4**<sup>1</sup>
  <sub>Built from source code released on April 12, 2010.</sub>

  ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/security/nss/releases/NSS_3_12_4_RTM/msvc9/WINNT5.1_OPT.OBJ/nss-3.12.4.zip

  <sub><sup>1</sup> Requires the [Visual C++ 2008 x86 runtime libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368).</sub>
  <sub><sup>2</sup> Requires the [Visual C++ 2010 x86 runtime libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999).</sub>
  <sub><sup>3</sup> **Unofficial** release.</sub>

Comment: The sources are also available via HTTP https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/security/nss/releases/

Answer (score 4):

As of Tor Browser 8.5, The Tor Project provides `certutil` binaries for Windows, macOS, and GNU/Linux.  This is probably a preferable option compared to the other answers for users who are concerned about getting outdated versions (Tor Browser is based on latest Firefox ESR) or who are concerned about downloading sketchy binaries from random unknown people (The Tor Project has a pretty good reputation, and more importantly their builds are reproducible).

The Tor Browser `certutil` binaries can be downloaded from https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/ (onion service link is http://rqef5a5mebgq46y5.onion/torbrowser/ for those who prefer it); specifically you want the `mar-tools` downloads.

Full disclosure: I wrote the patch to Tor Browser that added these binaries to the build outputs.

Answer (score 2):

here's a relatively new Windows build of certutil.exe, with a script to batch-install CA certificates for all users on a Windows machine:
https://github.com/christian-korneck/firefox_add-certs/releases/tag/1.0